# jquery/javascript quickie, what are those parenthesis holding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run across a few javascript or jQuery functions that have an enclosed value or object at the end of the method.  Example:

```
(function ($) {
        var delay = 0;
        $.fn.translate3d = function (translations, speed, easing, complete) {
            var opt = $.speed(speed, easing, complete);
            opt.easing = opt.easing || 'ease';
            translations = $.extend({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, translations);

            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);

                $this.css({
                    transitionDuration: opt.duration + 'ms',
                    transitionTimingFunction: opt.easing,
                    transform: 'translate3d(' + translations.x + 'px, ' + translations.y + 'px, ' + translations.z + 'px)'
                });

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $this.css({
                        transitionDuration: '0s',
                        transitionTimingFunction: 'ease'
                    });

                    opt.complete();
                }, opt.duration + (delay || 0));
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

**Or**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d, t) {

<snip>

    })(document, 'script');
</script>
```

What is the purpose of those  parenthesis-enclosed items at the end of the function? I found a couple answers here on SO but nothing that cleared it up.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It forms a self invoking anonymous function. The advantage is that all identifiers get scoped to within that function, rather than having a global scope.

This is a good link that goes into more details: http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Here's an example:

```
(function() {
  var foo = "bar";

  console.log(foo); // prints bar
})();

console.log(foo);  // prints undefined since foo is scoped within the function
```

It might be easier to understand the above code-snippet when re-written like this:

```
function fun() {
  var foo = "bar";
  console.log(foo);
}

fun();
```

The two code snippets achieve the same thing. The only difference is, int he first snippet, you do not name your function and then call it. You instead create it as an anonymous function, and invoke it immediately.

This is also useful when you want to bind an object to a certain variable, such as is being done with `jQuery` in your code snippet:

```
var $ = {}; // define $ to an empty object instead of the jQuery object

(function($) {
  // within this function, $ will always be the jQuery object
  // protecting you from re-definitions outside the funciton
  console.log($);
})(jQuery);
```

The above code snippet creates an anonymous function that takes a single argument, `$`, then immediately calls the function passing in the `jQuery` object, ensuring that within the function `$` will always reference the `jQuery`object.

Another interesting application of self-invoking anonymous functions is when you want to bind a variable to a particular object in case of delayed execution.

```
var markers = []; //an array of google map markers

for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  // do something with markers[i];

  // then schedule it for removal after 2 seconds
  setTimeout(function() { markers[i].setMap(null); }, 2000);
}
```

The problem with the above code snippet is that when the marker removal code runs 2 seconds later, the value of `i` would have changed by then since the loop would have proceeded. This can be remedied by creating a closure using a self invoking anon function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  // do something with markers[i];

  // then schedule it for removal after 2 seconds
  (function(j) {
    setTimeout(function() { markers[j].setMap(null); }, 2000);
  })(i);

}
```

Now, `j` is bound to the current value of `i`, and so when the removal code runs 2 seconds later, it runs on the intended value of `i`, even though `i` has since changed.

Comment: thanks!  appreciate you taking some time to write a detailed answer

Answer (score 3):

It defines an anonymous function with the arguments, assigns the values to the function's parameters, and then calls it.

The advantage to this method is that you don't pollute your namespace with functions and variables that you won't use anywhere else aside from within the function.

To be more elaborate,

`(function() {}  ...` declares the anonymous function and adding `()` at the end calls that function that was just created.